"React Native Navigation Error: 'NAVIGATE' with Payload Not Handled by Any Navigator"
I'm working on a React Native app with Expo that uses React Navigation to handle multiple screens. I'm encountering an error when trying to navigate to a specific screen. The error message is: The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"EnterCompetitionPage"} was not handled by any navigator.
Here is the code:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store, updateUserId } from './store'; // Redux store and action

// Importing components for each page
import registerPage from './screens/RegisterPage';
import StartRace from './screens/StartRace';
import competitionWaitingPage from './screens/CompetitionWaitingPage';
import competitionStartRace from './screens/CompetitionStartRace';
import TakePhoto from './screens/TakePhoto';
import recordOdometer from './screens/RecordOdometer';
import checkpointSummary from './screens/CheckpointSummary';
import CompetitionEndRace from './screens/CompetitionEndRace';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function Index({ navigation }: { navigation: any }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Listening to authentication state changes using Firebase
    onAuthStateChanged(FIREBASE_AUTH, (user) => {
      store.dispatch(updateUserId(user?.uid));
      setUser(user);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            {user ? (
              <Stack.Group>
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="RegisterPage"
                  component={registerPage}
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="EnterCompetitionPage"
                  component={StartRace}
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="CompetitionWaitingPage"
                  component={competitionWaitingPage}
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="CompetitionStartRace"
                  component={competitionStartRace}
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="TakePhotoPage"
                  component={TakePhoto}
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="RecordOdometerPage"
                  component={recordOdometer}
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="CheckpointSummary"
                  component={checkpointSummary}
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="CompetitionEndRace"
                  component={CompetitionEndRace}
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
              </Stack.Group>
            ) : (
              <Stack.Group>
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="RegisterPage"
                  component={registerPage}
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
              </Stack.Group>
            )}
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});


I'm trying to navigate to the EnterCompetitionPage, but I'm encountering the following error : The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"EnterCompetitionPage"} was not handled by any navigator.
Questions:

Why am I getting the error that the navigator cannot handle the 'NAVIGATE' action?
Is there something wrong with the way I am handling navigation or setting up my navigator?
Please help me.

What I've Tried:

Checked Screen Names: Ensured that the screen names match exactly with those defined in the Stack.Navigator.
Verified Navigation Props: Made sure the navigation prop is passed correctly.
Independent Navigation Container: I'm using independent={true} to have a separate navigation tree.
Checked User State: Verified that the user authentication state updates correctly and displays the appropriate screens.


Can you post your navigate call
